# Vuetify + Flex: justify-space-evenly doesn't work on v-slide-group

Tags: flexbox, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to evenly align `v-slide-group-items` within a `v-slide-group` using any of the justify-space-* classes, but it ignores the justify-space-* setting and places all `v-slide-group-items` to the left instead of spreading them over the width of the `v-slide-group`.

**Vuetify Play (re-production link):** [v-slide-group + justify-soace-evenly playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-slide-group class="d-flex justify-space-evenly" show-arrows>
        <v-slide-group-item>
          <div v-for="n in 3" class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center ma-4">
            <span class="text-caption">Publisher</span>
            <v-icon class="text-center justify-center" icon="mdi-domain" size="large"></v-icon>
            <p>Test</p>
          </div>
        </v-slide-group-item>
      </v-slide-group>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the component API doesn't support flex classes like that for whatever reason.  You can always apply the flex property manually with regular CSS, `.v-slide-group__content { justify-content: space-evenly; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you currently have the CSS classes on v-slide-group will not have the desired effect as there are elements in-between this and the items. I would suggest adding a div in-between to resolve this.

```
<v-slide-group show-arrows>
  <v-slide-group-item>
    <div class="d-flex justify-space-evenly w-100">
      <div v-for="n in 3" class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center ma-4">
        <span class="text-caption">Publisher</span>
        <v-icon class="text-center justify-center" icon="mdi-domain" size="large"></v-icon>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-slide-group-item>
</v-slide-group>
```

Please see [example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the grid system approach.

Here is a demo-

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp().use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-slide-group>
        <v-row>
          <v-col v-for="n in 3" align="center">
            <v-slide-group-item>
              <div>
                <span class="text-caption">Publisher</span>
                <v-icon class="text-center justify-center" icon="mdi-domain" size="large"></v-icon>
                <p>Test</p>
              </div>
            </v-slide-group-item>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-slide-group>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```